# Passing data on Callback onListItemClick to a Fragment

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments

I'm trying to learn fragment, I'm using the Multiform project template created in eclipse. I run into a problem when passing data in the `onListItemClick.` I have data loaded in to a SQL database this is a list of names and addresses. in the list view i have the names listed and I want to list the name and address when a name is click in the `ListView`. There maybe a better way to do this but I only have this to start with.

```
public class CustomerListFragment extends ListFragment {
       private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
public interface Callbacks {

    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() {
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
    }
};

 @Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);
    long myLong = values.get(position).getId();  
    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(String.valueOf(myLong));
}
```

In the Detail fragment I have the following. Even I pass the Id from the data the ARG_ITEM_ID always have the value of the id for the component.

```
public class CustomerDetailFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "_id";
DataSource cusdatasource;
sqlCustomer selectedCustomer;

 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    datasource = new DataSource(getActivity());
    datasource.open();

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
       mItem = DummyContent.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
    selectedCustomer = datasource.getCustomer("here I need the _id from the list item clicked");

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_detail_customer, container, false);
    if (selectedCustomer != null) {
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText1)).setText(selectedCustomer.getName());
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText2)).setText(selectedCustomer.getStreet());
        ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText(selectedCustomer.getCitySZ());
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

On the main activity I have this:

```
 public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(CustomerDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
        CustomerDetailFragment fragment = new CustomerDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.customer_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to pass that `myLong` value through the `Callbacks` interface to the `DetailsFragment` you're not doing it right. The idea of that callback is for someone to implement it and register itself as a listener so when the user clicks the list item that implementation is called(and not just have an empty implementation which will not do anything). You could leave the communication between the fragments for the activity which shows those fragments to manage. For example:

```
public class CustomerListFragment extends ListFragment {
       private Callbacks mCallbacks;

public interface Callbacks {

    public void onItemSelected(String id);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
            mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Casting the activity as a Callbacks listener failed"
                + ex);
        mCallbacks = null;
    }
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) {
    long myLong = values.get(position).getId();  
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onItemSelected(myLong);
    }
}
// ...
```

And then in your activity which holds the two fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements CustomerListFragment.Callbacks {

// ...

public void onItemSelected(Long id) {
    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
    arguments.putLong(CustomerDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
    CustomerDetailFragment fragment = new CustomerDetailFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.customer_detail_container, fragment)
            .commit();
}


//...
```

And then retrieve the id from the arguments passed to the `CustomerDetailFragment` :

```
long theId = -1;
if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {
      theId = getArguments().getLong(ARG_ITEM_ID));
}
selectedCustomer = datasource.getCustomer(theId);
```

Comment: I updated my code above and change onListItemClick to your sample code, but I still can see how to get the id to CustomerDetailFragment onCreate. My MainActivity extends FragmentActivity.

Comment: @KimHJ I've edited my answer. Also look at the `CustomerListFragment` class. There is no need to convert the id to string, just use a long value.

Comment: I tried to add the procedure updateCustomerInfo(String Id) in CustomerDetailFragment but it crash on the line datasourse.open; I also noticed that I get two things in the id (the customers _id and another saying (id=830022855688)

Comment: @KimHJ Using my code you should be able to pass the id from `onListItemClick` to the `CustomerDetailFragment` fragment. You can use an update method on the fragment if the fragment is already in the activity, but in your case you just add it so you have to use the bundle. I don't see how you could possible get two id values when you pass only one value through.

Comment: After I changed everything to long I get the right id and only one. Now I just have to find why I don't get the right person, I always get the first.